# Agglomerative hierachial clustering using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Plotting a dendogram from a agglomerative hierachial clustering does not yield the expected results. I have attached the example of the expected output in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK1rY.png) . The y axis shows the treatment groups.

My MWE is

```
library(cluster)
dist<-daisy(cluster, metric = "gower")
kaari <-hclust(dist, method = "ward.D2")
plot(kaari,cex = 0.6, hang = -1)
```

Here is the data frame:

```
structure(list(Variety = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Cal J", 
"Pesa F1", "Rambo F1", "Riograde"), class = "factor"), Sample.Part = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("% fruit damage", 
"Intermediate", "Lower", "Upper"), class = "factor"), overall = c(8.33, 
15.83, 18.33, 18.33, 16.67, 15.83, 17.5, 15, 14.17, 16.67, 15, 
18.33, 6.67, 14.17, 6.67, 15.83, 10, 12.5, 10, 15, 35, 55, 50, 
25, 12.5, 11.67, 12.5, 13.33, 15.83, 13.33, 14.17, 10, 11.67, 
15.83, 8.33, 10.83, 7.5, 7.5, 10.83, 9.17, 5.83, 5.83, 10, 17.5, 
20, 12.5, 20, 5, 18.33, 15, 15, 12.5, 10, 15.83, 20.83, 15.83, 
18.33, 10, 11.67, 18.33, 10.83, 6.67, 7.5, 14.17, 6.67, 10.83, 
37.5, 17.5, 25, 15, 30, 20, 24.17, 22.5, 16.67, 19.17, 14.17, 
24.17, 26.67, 20.83, 16.67, 17.5, 14.17, 20, 12.5, 20.83, 11.67, 
6.67, 12.5, 11.67, 55, 55, 55, 60, 55, 57.5, 24.17, 28.33, 19.17, 
21.67, 20, 18.33, 24.17, 20.83, 17.5, 15, 16.67, 15, 15, 10.83, 
11.67, 16.67, 14.17, 10, 30, 45, 55, 42.5, 55, 37.5, 33.33, 20.83, 
20, 17.5, 18.33, 20, 28.33, 13.33, 17.5, 13.33, 20.83, 11.67, 
11.67, 10.83, 13.33, 8.33, 8.33, 13.33, 55, 40, 55, 52.5, 45, 
45, 12.5, 17.5, 15, 21.67, 17.5, 17.5, 14.17, 14.17, 16.67, 14.17, 
19.17, 15, 10.83, 13.33, 6.67, 9.17, 8.33, 13.33, 45, 50, 40, 
35, 55, 45, 10.83, 9.17, 23.33, 22.5, 15.83, 11.67, 26.67, 8.33, 
20, 12.5, 10.83, 18.33, 9.17, 7.5, 9.17, 7.5, 5.83, 13.33, 37.5, 
35, 45, 22.5, 30, 25, 15, 13.33, 20, 13.33, 20, 20, 9.17, 21.67, 
12.5, 10, 14.17, 24.17, 10.83, 10, 13.33, 9.17, 11.67, 10.83, 
45, 45, 42.5, 30, 55, 40, 11.67, 21.67, 18.33, 16.67, 16.67, 
16.67, 14.17, 15, 15.83, 20.83, 12.5, 16.67, 10, 12.5, 9.17, 
10, 7.5, 6.67, 27.5, 30, 32.5, 45, 17.5, 25, 15.83, 15.83, 17.5, 
13.33, 12.5, 13.33, 13.33, 10.83, 19.17, 12.5, 13.33, 12.5, 7.5, 
8.33, 9.17, 5.83, 10.83, 10.83, 47.5, 15, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 
18.33, 12.5, 11.67, 10.83, 13.33, 13.33, 12.5, 10, 10, 13.33, 
15, 6.67, 14.17, 7.5, 7.5, 10.83, 7.5, 22.5, 15, 22.5, 20, 25, 
15)), .Names = c("Variety", "Sample.Part", "overall"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-288L))
```

My first and second columns in my data set are categorical while the third is numeric, I have attached the the data here.

```
Variety    Sample.Part         overall
Cal J        Lower              8.33
Cal J        Lower             15.83
Cal J        Lower             18.33
Cal J        Lower             18.33
Cal J        Lower             16.67
Cal J        Lower             15.83
Cal J        Intermediate      17.50
Cal J        Intermediate      15.00
Cal J        Intermediate      14.17
Cal J        Intermediate      16.67
Cal J        Intermediate      15.00
Cal J        Intermediate      18.33
Cal J        Upper             6.67
Cal J        Upper             14.17
Cal J        Upper             6.67
Cal J        Upper             15.83
Cal J        Upper             10.00
Cal J        Upper             12.50
Cal J        % fruit damage    10.00
Cal J        % fruit damage    15.00
Cal J        % fruit damage    35.00
Cal J        % fruit damage    55.00
Cal J        % fruit damage    50.00
```

I would like to have the factor levels in the first column appear as leaf nodes in the y axis. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not include your data via an image.  No one wants to type it all in again. Instead,  please use `dput(MyData)` to make a text representation of your data that you can paste into your question and then we can cut and paste into R.

Comment: I have edited my question as required @G5W

Comment: The data that you provided has 288 points. Your sample output has 11 data points with names that don't seem anything like your sample data. Do you want the dendrogram for the 288 points? It is kind of busy. You say that you want the y axis to represent your treatment groups. How are those groups recorded in the data that you provided?

Comment: Sample output is not related with my sample data its just the reflection of what i would like to be achieved. the y axis should be the groups in the first column of my sample data (variety). Yes i would like the dendogram for the 288 data points @G5W